# Are psychic abilities more akin to fantasy or science fiction? why is this?

Tags: magic, science-fiction-genre, fantasy-genre, psychic

Psychic abilities like telekinesis, telepathy, mind-control, clairvoyance. Basically powers involving the mind.

Abilities that let you levitate objects with your thoughts or speak to another person without uttering a word sound very much like magic - a thing of fantasy, yet is often  portrayed in science fiction (sometimes explained as mutation or superhuman ability or an alien trait)
Take the example of Vulcan Mind-meld from Star-Trek. A telepathic technique used by vulcans that merges the minds of the two individuals via physical contact (finger-tip points targeted at the partner's skull temples)

If Psychic powers fall under science fiction, what sets it apart from magic (fantasy) ?

Comment: One possible answer would be that if psychic powers happen in a story and setting that is otherwise science fiction (the Lensman series, Star wars, Star Trek) they make it seem a bit more like fantasy but the story is still the science fiction genre but closer to the border with fantasy than it would otherwise be.  Similarly  Psychic powers in a story and setting that is otherwise fantasy might move it a bit closer to the border with science fiction but it would still be fantasy.  The telepathy scene in LOTR surprised me because I previously read of telepathy only in science fiction.

Comment: Another possible answer would be that if an otherwise science fiction story has Psychic powers the main story is science fiction and the psychic powers are fantasy, thus making the story, for example, 90 percent science fiction and ten percent fantasy.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The essence of SF is that the story relies on fictional science or engineering.  The essence of fantasy is that relies on fictional magic or the fictional supernatural.  So whether psychic powers are SF or fantasy depends on whether they are depicted as being part of of systematic body of knowledge or "they just happen because she's special".

So, to answer the question "If Psychic powers fall under science fiction, what sets it apart from magic (fantasy)?", I'd say that while they *can* fall under SF and sometimes do, they default to fantasy in most people's minds because stories featuring them are usually done as fantasy.

Comment: I'm just gonna leave this here: [Clarke's Laws](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Clarke%27s_three_laws) (and in particular, #3...)

Comment: First of thanks for that answer
Second, I've found the first thing you said about the essence of science fiction very interesting. A follow-up if I may. I can't think of an example title on the fly, but say a story does involve something that would have no ground on actual science but does have its own pseudo/fictional science that explains itself, this makes it fall under the sci-fi genre, do I have this right?

Comment: Sure. The key thing that makes SF is that it the story turns on a body of knowledge which is systematic and intelligible and objective in the context of the story. Classic examples of "scientific magic" include Randall Garret's Lord Darcy series and De Camp and Pratt's Mathematics of Magic series. In neither case do they present a coherent, detailed blueprint of how to do magic -- how could they? -- but in the context of the story, magic is consistent, intelligible, and objective. And in fact, just about no SF anywhere is based only on actual science -- stories that do tend to be dull.

Comment: Thank you again! that clears up alot of the confusion I had of where exactly the line is drawn between the two genres

Comment: Huh.  I'd say that while psychic powers *can* be fantasy and sometimes are, they're more usually science fiction.  Julian May's "Saga of the Exiles" being the central example in my head.  Maybe the close-voters are right. :-)  (Can you provide an example of psychic powers in a work of fantasy?  I can't think of one offhand, except cases like Pern that are deliberately fantasy stories told in SF settings.)

Comment: @Harry Johnston I guess I don't understand what you mean by "psychic powers." To me, it doesn't much matter what you call something, if you accomplish changes to the physical world -- starting a fire, killing someone, levitating a ball -- without using any of the physical methods available to us, it's magic/psychical/whatever. As far as the real world (as we currently know it) is concerned, "magic" and "psychic" are simply two labels for the same thing.  And that thing permeates fantasy.  Even LotR, that least overtly magical of fantasies, has some.

Comment: The thing that might make a particular power stfnal rather than fantasy is not the name you call it, but how it is used in the story. If it's presented as part of a technology or science, then its stfnal. Labeling it as stfnal without backing it up is simply sloppy writing. And nearly all things called "psychic" in fantastic fiction are indistinguishable from mind magic.

Comment: Broadly speaking psychic powers are "powers of the mind" like ESP whereas magic is typically invoked via a spell or charm of some sort, a magic item, or by asking the assistance of some supernatural entity.  But I'm not sure what you mean by "mind magic", can you give a specific example?

Comment: Dungeons and Dragons, for example, has separate systems for magic and for psionics, they are quite different things.  So OK, I guess that's *one* example of psychic powers in a fantasy setting. :-)